# Why is Google Calendar API throwing Error Bad request using node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, bad-request

the idea of the following program is, that for every customer, booked a event, a google calendar entry with name, phonenumber... will be created. The programm is working if i used the defined const lol and lil.
But mostly the eventdates are on different dates so my idea was to fetch the results of the query and gave it to const eventdatestart and const eventdateend. If im now running the code my console logs "Error at insertEvent --> Error: Bad Request. Does anybody know how to fix the problem.

My Programm:

```
(function addEvents(){ //created IEE Function
    const { google } = require('googleapis');
    require('dotenv').config();
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    const CREDENTIALS = JSON.parse(process.env.CREDENTIALS);
    const calendarId = process.env.CALENDAR_ID;
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events';
    const calendar = google.calendar({version : "v3"});

    //Google API Authentification to use and write Google Calendar API
    const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
        CREDENTIALS.client_email,
        null,
        CREDENTIALS.private_key,
        SCOPES
    );

    // create connection to database
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "produktdatenbank"
    });
    
    //connect to database to work 
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //get query against kusdatencustomer
        con.query("SELECT * FROM kursdatencustomer WHERE bookingincreatment = 'NEIN'", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;

            //check if result[] is not empty
            if (result.length > 0){
                
                for (let number = 0; number < result.length; number++) {
                    const bookingnumber = result[number].bookingnumber;
                    const bookingnumbermail = result[number].bookingnumbermail;
                    let eventdatestart = result[number].bookingeventdatestart; //not correct format 
                    console.log(eventdatestart);
                    const eventdateend = result[number].bookingeventdateend; // not correct format
                    console.log(eventdateend);
                    const bookingcustomername = result[number].bookingcustomername;
                    const bookingcustomersurename = result[number].bookingcustomersurename;
                    const bookingcustomeremail = result[number].bookingcustomermail;
                    const bookingcustomerphone = result[number].bookingcustomerphone;
                    const bookingcustomerlevel = result[number].bookingcustomerlevel;
                    const bookingevent = result[number].bookingevent;
                    const bookingincreatment = result[number].bookingincreatment;
            
                    // define event which will be posted to google calendar
                    //const lol = '2022-10-23T12:00:00+02:00';
                    //const lil = '2022-10-23T14:00:00+02:00';
                    const event = {
                        'id': bookingnumber,
                        'summary': bookingevent,
                        'description': "Buchungsnummer: "+ bookingnumbermail + "<br>" + bookingcustomername + " " + bookingcustomersurename + "<br>" + "Level: " + bookingcustomerlevel + "<br>" + bookingcustomeremail + "<br>" + bookingcustomerphone ,
                        'colorId': "3",
                        'start': {
                            'dateTime': eventdatestart,//bad request if using lol it will work
                            'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin'
                        },
                        'end': {
                            'dateTime': eventdateend, //bad request if using lil it will work
                            'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin'
                        },
                    };

                    //insert event to goggle calendar get authorisation
                    const insertEvent = async (event) => {
                        try {
                            const response = await calendar.events.insert({
                                auth: auth,
                                calendarId: calendarId,
                                resource: event
                            });
            
                            if (response['status'] == 200 && response['statusText'] === 'OK') {
                                return "Event Inserted sucessfully";
                            } else {
                                return "Failed to insert event";
                            }
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log (`Error at insertEvent --> ${error}`);
                            return 0;
                        } 
                    };
            
            
                    const insertNewEvent = async (event) => {
                        try {
                            const res = await insertEvent(event);
                            console.log(res)
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    };
            
                    insertNewEvent(event);

                    //set inserted events to inserted at db 
                    var sql = "UPDATE kursdatencustomer SET bookingincreatment = 'JA' WHERE bookingincreatment = 'NEIN'";
                    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });
                }; // end ForLoop
                con.end(); // end connection to database
            } else {
                console.log('No Events to add');
                con.end(); // end connection to database
            }
        });
    });
    setTimeout(addEvents,30000); // call function addEvents every 30s
}());
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "calendar-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "googleapis": "^108.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

And structure of my MYSQL DB:
[structure of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k7O2.png)

Comment: Ok found the solution for this problem. Problem was at MYSQL db. Eventdatestart and end have to be entered YYYY-MM-ddTHH:MM:SSTimeoffset. I usually saved it like 'YYYY-MM-ddTHH:MM:SSTimeoffset' so google can not read the string as a date.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution for this problem. Problem was at MYSQL db. `Eventdatestart` and end have to be entered `YYYY-MM-ddTHH:MM:SSTimeoffset`. I usually saved it like `YYYY-MM-ddTHH:MM:SSTimeoffset` so google can not read the string as a date.